# dynamically set checkbox checked if value present in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How to dynamically checked checkbox based on database value which are present or not null

```
@foreach (abc.Models.xyz entry in entrydetails)
        {
        <div style="height:auto !important;max-height:160px; overflow-y:auto;width:79%;">   
        @{
           List<abc.Models.Singer> singerobjlist = abc.Service.Class1.singerlist();        
            }   

           @foreach (abc.Models.Singer singerobj in singerobjlist)
           {    
          <div class="boxcheck">
          <input type="checkbox" value='@singerobj.Singer1' name="Singer1l"/>
         <label>@singerobj.Singer1</label>
          </div>
           }

         </div>
        }
```

Dear All... I have declared foreach loop at the top which contain all entry in database corresponding to singer1-singer7. Now below foreach loop I have declared another foreach loop which will dynamically display all singer name in view page. I want to do that all those singer whose not null in outer foreach loop that singer name must be checked by inner foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" value='@singerobj.Singer1' name="Singer1l"
@(singerobj.Singer1!=null ? Html.Raw(" checked=\"checked\"") : null)
/>
```

Comment: Works fine, tanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<div class="boxcheck">
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.singerobj.Singer1)
  <label>@singerobj.Singer1</label>
</div>
```

Comment: my all singer name should be displayed which are checked or unchecked... please help to us